# Switching between the execution of two function contexts

Tags: c, signals, ucontext

I am trying to write a program where I have defined two functions and one prints odd numbers while the other prints even numbers. The program executes a function for a certain amount of time and when it receives an alarm signal, it starts executing the second function after saving the current function's context. When it receives the next alarm signal, it resumes the execution of the first function from its last saved context.

I have used the functions getcontext and swapcontext for this.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<ucontext.h>

ucontext_t c1, c2, cmain;
int switch_context = 0, first_call = 1;

void handler(int k)
{
 switch_context = 1;
}

void nextEven()
{
 int i;
 for(i = 0; ; i += 2)
 {
  if(switch_context)
  {
   alarm(2);
   switch_context = 0;
   if(first_call)
   {
    first_call = 0;
    swapcontext(&c1, &cmain);
   }
   else
   {
    swapcontext(&c1, &c2);
    }
   }
   printf("even:%d\n", i);
   sleep(1);
  }
 }

 void nextOdd()
 {
  int j;
  for(j = 1; ; j += 2)
  { 
   if(switch_context)
   {
    alarm(2);
    switch_context = 0;
    if(first_call)
    {
     first_call = 0;
     swapcontext(&c2, &cmain);
    }
    else
    {
     swapcontext(&c2, &c1);
    } 
  }

  printf("odd:%d\n", j);
  sleep(1);
 }
}

int main()
{
 signal(SIGALRM, handler);
 alarm(2);
 getcontext(&cmain);
 if(first_call) nextOdd();
 nextEven();
}
```

The output I received is:

```
odd:1
odd:3
even:0
even:2
odd:4
odd:6
even:8
even:10
odd:12
```

Why is it restoring contexts every time but still printing the values of the function nextEven() ?

Comment: Given that your functions asynchronously access non-readonly, non lock-free-atomic, non `volatile sigatomic_t` objects, the behavior is *undefined*.

Comment: @EOF That is true but it is also an unhelpful wall of jargon.

Comment: @zwol: Why that? It is precise and clear. It uses standard terms, not some wishy-washy sentence.

Comment: @Olaf You need to stop assuming that everyone has memorized all of the standards.

Comment: @zwol: I don't (you should stop assuming what I mean). Aber es ist einfacher wenn wir alle die gleiche Sprache sprechen. Im Zweifel muss man halt die Bedeutung nachschlagen. (didn't get what I mean? See? it is easier to use commonly accepted language and terms. Here it would be English, not German, in C programming the terms from the standard. Everyone asking here can bne expected to use google and read a C book. After all, we are **no** tutoring site!)

Comment: @Olaf In a way we are a tutoring site, at least partly. I would seek a middleground here. Use specific termini but try to remain understandable to a larger audience. Just out of curiosity: How many C programmers understand "non lock-free-atomic" right away and couldn't it be written a bit easier? I will google it now. (Also "non-readonly" means the same as "writable", doesn't it?)

Comment: @Trilarion: "How many C programmers understand "non lock-free-atomic" - Possibly not all who **should** know about them. But you swapped cause and effect. Any programmer working at that level with concurrency should be aware about those issues. For missing/unknown terms: there is google, Wikipedia and a lot of specialised sites like stack overflow. I'm ESL, so what do you think I do first if I read an unknow word here? Ask? No, I look it up! And that's what I **do expect** from any programmer - beginner or senior. Basta!

Comment: @Trilarion: "Non-readonly" is not the same as "writeable". These are two different and - in the first place - not related things. But feel free to ask the author of the comment, I'm confident he can express himself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program contains two outright bugs and several infelicities.

The first bug is very simple:

```
int switch_context = 0, first_call = 1;
```

The variable `switch_context` is used to communicate from an asynchronous signal handler to the main program.  Therefore, for correct operation, it *must* be given the type `volatile sig_atomic_t`.  (If you don't do this, the compiler may assume that nobody ever sets `switch_context` to 1, and delete all the calls to `swapcontext`!)  `sig_atomic_t` might be as small as `char`, but you only ever set `switch_context` to 0 or 1, so that's not a problem.

The second bug is more involved: you aren't initializing your coroutine contexts at all.  This is finicky and poorly explained by the manpages.  You must first call `getcontext` on each context.  For each context other than the original context, you must then allocate a stack for it, and apply `makecontext` to define the entry point.  If you don't do all of these things, `swapcontext`/`setcontext` will crash.  A full initialization looks something like this:

```
getcontext(&c1);
c1.uc_stack.ss_size = 1024 * 1024 * 8;
c1.uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 8);
if (!c1.uc_stack.ss_sp) {
  perror("malloc");
  exit(1);
}
makecontext(&c1, nextEven, 0);
```

(There's no good way to know how much stack to allocate, but eight megabytes ought to be enough for anyone.  I suppose you could use `getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK)`.  In a production-grade program I would use `mmap` so that I could then use `mprotect` to define guard bands on both sides of the stack, but that's a lot of extra code for a demo like this.)

On to the infelicities.  You should always use `sigaction` to set signal handlers, not `signal`, because `signal` is underspecified.  (Note that `sigaction` is not available on Windows.  That is because signals are *fake* on Windows and should not be used at all.)  You should also not use `alarm` nor `sleep`, because they are *also* underspecified, and may interact catastrophically with each other.  Instead use `setitimer` (or `timer_settime`, but that's new in POSIX.1-2008, whereas the ucontext functions were *withdrawn* in -2008) and `nanosleep`.  This also has the advantage that you can set a repeating timer and forget about it.

Also, your program can be substantially simplified by realizing that you only need *two* contexts, not three.  Use `c2` for the original context, and directly call `nextOdd`.  This eliminates `first_call` and `cmain` and the complicated switching logic in `nextOdd` and `nextEven`.

Finally, your loop index variables in `nextOdd` and `nextEven` should be `unsigned` so that the behavior is well-defined upon wrapping around (if you care to wait 2^31 seconds), and you should set stdout to line-buffered so that each line of output appears immediately even if redirected to a file.

Putting it all together I get this:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 /* ucontext was XSI in Issue 6 and withdrawn in 7 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define UNUSED(arg) arg __attribute__((unused))
#else
#define UNUSED(arg) arg
#endif

static ucontext_t c1, c2;
static volatile sig_atomic_t switch_context = 0;

static void
handler(int UNUSED(signo))
{
  switch_context = 1;
}

static void
nextEven(void)
{
  struct timespec delay = { 1, 0 };
  for (unsigned int i = 0;; i += 2) {
    if (switch_context) {
      switch_context = 0;
      swapcontext(&c1, &c2);
    }
    printf("even:%d\n", i);
    nanosleep(&delay, 0);
  }
}

static void
nextOdd(void)
{
  struct timespec delay = { 1, 0 };
  for (unsigned int i = 1;; i += 2) {
    if (switch_context) {
      switch_context = 0;
      swapcontext(&c2, &c1);
    }
    printf("odd:%d\n", i);
    nanosleep(&delay, 0);
  }
}

int
main(void)
{
  /* flush each printf as it happens */
  setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);

  /* initialize main context */
  getcontext(&c2);

  /* initialize coroutine context */
  getcontext(&c1);
  c1.uc_stack.ss_size = 1024 * 1024 * 8;
  c1.uc_stack.ss_sp = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 8);
  if (!c1.uc_stack.ss_sp) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(1);
  }
  makecontext(&c1, nextEven, 0);

  /* initiate periodic timer signals */
  struct sigaction sa;
  memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);
  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
  if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, 0)) {
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
  }

  struct itimerval it;
  memset(&it, 0, sizeof it);
  it.it_interval.tv_sec = 2;
  it.it_value.tv_sec = 2;
  if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it, 0)) {
    perror("setitimer");
    exit(1);
  }

  nextOdd(); /* does not return */
}
```